# How to change a string in a function when calling a function after it passes through list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, basehttpserver

Is there way to change the word cat to dog in string() when calling it in main()?

For example:

```
def notimportant2("Not using this."

def notimportant1("Not worried about this.")

def string():
    print ("This cat was scared.")


def contentList(skip_name=''):  # All content functions in list 
    functions = [notimportant1, notimportant2, string]
    for f in functions:
        if f.__name__ != skip_name:
            f()

def main():
    contentList('notimportant2')  # This calls notimportant1() and string() but ignores notimportant2
        # while print string() do the below:
        for words in string():
            str.replace("cat", "dog")
            # Print "The dog was scared."

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `replace` returns a copy of the original string with all occurrences of substring 'cat' replaced by 'dog'. You can assign this new string to the original variable. 
[Refer Python Documentation for usage of replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)

```
def notimportant2():
    pass

def notimportant1():
    pass

def string():
    return ["This cat was scared."]


def contentList(skip_name=''):
    functions = [notimportant1, notimportant2, string]
    for f in functions:
        if f.__name__ != skip_name:
            f()

def main():
    contentList('notimportant2') 
    for words in string():
      words=words.replace("cat", "dog")
      print(words)

main()
```

Comment: In my main code, I am getting 'Nonetype' object is not iterable.